# Java JDBC exec procedure with sql statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to execute this SQL code:

```
exec procedure(param, param, param, param)

select * from bla_bla_table;

commit;
```

And get a ResultList from this query.

I tried to do it like this:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call procedure(param,param,param,param)}");
stmt.execute();
```

How can I insert sql statement `select * from bla_bla_table;` here before `commit` to get the ResultSet. I tried a lot of ways to do that... but nothing helps.

Comment: u want to get records using procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // Disable Auto Commit
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call procedure(param,param,param,param)}");
stmt.execute();

Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery("select * from bla_bla_table"); // Result set for Query

connection.commit();
```

Comment: Oh.. man, you're awesome! Im a little bit new to JDBC, so your answer was very helpfull for me! Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after the execution of your code.

```
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(string);
ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
// now iterate the resultset.
```

Before everything you should make sure that you run a transaction by setting the autocommit option of the connection to false.

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```